# Pagination not working in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-pagination

I am trying to set pagination in Laravel 5.1, here is what I am trying to do:

```
$bridal_requests_data = \DB::table('bridal_requests')->leftJoin('audiences', function($join) {
                        $join->on('bridal_requests.id', '=', 'audiences.request_id');
                        })
                        ->orderBy('bridal_requests.id', 'DESC')->paginate('15', array('bridal_requests.*'));
```

it is giving the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as aggregate from `bridal_requests` left join `audiences` on `bridal_requests' at line 1 (SQL: select count(`bridal_requests`.*) as aggregate from`bridal_requests`left join`audiences`on`bridal_requests`.`id`=`audiences`.`request_id`)

As stated above, it is not working for `bridal_requests.*`, but if I use `brial_requests.id` then it works, but I need to use get all data from `bridal_requests` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$bridal_requests_data = \DB::table('bridal_requests')->select('bridal_requests.*')->leftJoin('audiences', function($join) {
                        $join->on('bridal_requests.id', '=', 'audiences.request_id');
                        })
                        ->orderBy('bridal_requests.id', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
```